# How to Autofit an Excel range in Outlook email?

Tags: vba, outlook

I send an Excel range consisting of multiple tables in an Outlook email.

I'd like to autofit the content when displayed in the email.

```vb
With newEmail
    .to = 123@email.com
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "My Report"
    .HTMLBody = strbody & _
      HMOimg _
      & .HTMLBody
    
    .Display
    Set xInspect = newEmail.GetInspector
    Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor
    
'This Range consist of 3 tables, I just copied the whole range    
     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyData").Range("B24:Q133").Copy

'This one Autofit the column not the content itself in excel sheet,
' what I want to do is to Autofit the "content" when paste in the email

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HMO Overall AHT").Range("B24:Q133").Columns.autofit
 
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
   
    .Display
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you deal with well-formatted HTML string when the `HTMLBody` property is set.

The `wdFormatPlainText` paramter passed to the [PasteAndFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa220334(v=office.11)) method is used for pasting the content as plain, unformatted text. I'd suggest choosing other options such as `wdFormatOriginalFormatting` and etc.